# Issue with python json object special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have json string like below and need to remove few characters from it to get proper json string.

Input String:

```
["{\n \"id\": \"1234\", \n \"name\":\"aaa\", \n \"dept\": \"IT\"\n}, \n{\n \"id\": \"1234-AB\", \n \"name\":\"bbb\", \n \"dept\": \"IT\"\n}\n"]
```

Output:

```
[{"id": "1234", "name":"aaa", "dep": "IT"}, {"id": "1234-AB", "name": "bbb", "dept": "IT"}]
```

Can someone please throw an idea to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can be JSON string be like this? it's not possible

Comment: My guess is that's not really what your input looks like, but you have simply printed it incorrectly.  Show us how you got that string and we'll tell you how to handle it.  As it is. `json.loads(data[0])` should do it.

Comment: Is your input a list containing a single string, or a string literally beginning with the characters `["{`?

Comment: what, **exactly** is your input?

Comment: its actually sting pushing to sqs queue.. like {"a":"1"},{"b":"2"} , when we read it from queue the output like ["{\n \"a\": \"1\"\n},\n{ \n \"b\": \"2\" \n}\n"]. so we have to remove these additional chars added to actual string and send as pay load like [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"}]

Answer (score 1):

It may go without saying, but you really should fix the upstream program that generates this awful string.

With that being said, you could do some rudimentary string replacements on your example before you've got a valid JSON string that can be parsed with `json.loads()`:

```
import json

my_string = '["{\n "id": "1234", \n "name":"aaa", \n "dept": "IT"\n}, \n{\n "id": "1234-AB", \n "name":"bbb", \n "dept": "IT"\n}\n"]'
cleaned_string = my_string.replace('\n', '').replace('["', '[').replace('"]', ']')
json_object = json.loads(cleaned_string)
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/WeeklyCurlyTrialsoftware#main.py)